# Show a particular page of pdf file using c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, pdf

Is there any way to show a particular page of PDF file using C# / JQuery ?

Comment: do you want a page to be set when document is opened? or you want only a page to offer as download?

Comment: try this http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/459446-open-pdf-file-specified-page-c

Comment: this may be similar to what you want
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423922/open-a-pdf-file-programmatically-at-a-named-destination

Answer (score 5):

Adobe defines parameters that allow you to open a PDF document with a command or URL 
that specifies exactly what to display (a named destination or specific page), and how to 
display it (with a specific view, scrollbars, bookmarks, or highlighting, for example).

http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParams.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I don't want to open a file using Reader. I just want to show a particular page from PDF file on my webpage using c# / jQuery

Comment: Updated link: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You could try rendering the page of your PDF file as an image on your server, store it in a temporary file and show the image in the browser using JQuery or any other approach of your choice.